# enjoyed OR have enjoyed?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Should I choose ENJOYED or HAVE ENJOYED in this situation ?And WHY ?

> I (enjoyed/have enjoyed) working with my company but now I want to look for another job.

I think it should be 'I enjoyed ' because he /she now wants to look for another job meaning they no longer enjoy it ... but using 'but' in the following sentence indicates that there is a contradiction between the two (MAYBE they are still enjoying working there and want to look for another for another reason)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/258273/107114

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible. Because your employment continues up to the present, the perfect (*have enjoyed*) is more natural in this case (It doesn't imply that you enjoyed every minute, or even that you enjoyed it right to the end, but that you enjoyed it over a period which lasts to the present).

The simple past (*perfect*) in this case is a choice which excludes the present, and so might be seen as implying specifically that you stopped enjoying it at some point. This may or may not be what you want to imply.

Comment: How about have been enjoying?

Comment: _I have been enjoying_ suggests that it's temporary.